# Do I load a differnet phonegap.js for every device?

Tags: cordova

Is the phonegap.js file the same no matter what device you are running it on?
Here's my code.  What I'd like to do is pull in the latest version of PhoneGap instead of hosting it locally.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css">
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
<script src="phonegap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No each platform needs it's own specific phonegap.js We are working towards getting around this requirement but for now.

Android != iOS != BlackBerry != Windows Phone

when it comes to phonegap.js.